# sorting some weird array in php by a value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

How can i sort something like this

```
$a = array(
        0  =>  array(
                 'field' => array( 
                            'id'=>'valueid'
                  )
        )
);
```

by valueid? I have managed to sort it by field but i can't realize how to do this weird sorting

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "sort".

Comment: you may need [uasort](http://in2.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php)

Comment: Sorting the $a(0=>array()) by that 'valueid'

Answer (score 0):

```
usort($a, function($e1, $e2) {
    return $e1['field']['id'] > $e2['field']['id'];
});
```

Comment: This is the array Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [field] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => value
                        )

                )
        )
}

Comment: I'm not getting what do you want to sort then.

Comment: How can i use usort for my prev commen array?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`uasort()`](https://www.php.net/uasort)

```
uasort($a, function($x, $y) {
    return $x['field']['id'] > $y['field']['id'];
});
```